# Equals int and short c# returns false

Tags: c#, .net, compare, equality

Consider this code:

```
static int x2 = 10;

public static void Main()
{
     short y = 10;
     Console.WriteLine(y.Equals(x2)); //False
     Console.Read();
}
```

Why `y.Equals(x2)` returns `false`?

Comment: From doc; _If an implicit conversion between the obj argument and an `Int16` is defined and the argument is not typed as an `Object`, compilers perform an implicit conversion and call the `Equals(Int16)` method. Otherwise, they call the `Equals(Object)` method, which always returns `false` if its obj argument is not an `Int16` value._

Comment: No this is not my question

Comment: An int is not a short: please look at this: http://blog.coverity.com/2014/01/13/inconsistent-equality/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Int16.Equals` specific [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bs113b2h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> **Return Value**
>
> true if obj is an instance of Int16 and equals the value of this instance; otherwise, false.

---

<sub>This was my original answer, whilst it doesn't apply here, I've left it in as a note for what the `.Equals` method is checking for</sub>

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

> the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can read that the specific overload used:

> Returns a value indicating whether this instance is equal to a specified object.

And:

> true if obj is an instance of System.Int16 and equals the value of this instance; otherwise, false.

A `short` is not an `int`, so it returns `false`.