# Why short(-1) not equal to -1 in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4,.net 4.6.1 and VS 2015, I write a simple MVC app to pass a short type value from view to controller like this

```
public bool GetTheValue (short req_division)
{ return req_division == -1 ;}
```

The weird thing is when I pass -1 to req_division from my view, the result returned false. I don't know why is it happened. Can anyone explain it for me. 
Thank you very much !

Comment: What is the difference between `value` and `val`? And why do both exist?

Comment: And, as an aside, based on the versions you mentioned, you have the following syntax available:     `bool GetTheValue (short val) => val == -1;`

Comment: @TranQ post your *actual* code. What's bothering people is having to guess

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Besides the possible typo in your code, I found something strange in the evaluation that the Debug View does. See this code:

> [image]

The debugger says it is false, yet the code evaluates to true. Maybe you have hit a type conversion issue in the debugger. When changing the `int` to a `short`, the debugger thinks `i == j` evaluates to `true` after all.

Comment: There is no `Equals` used here @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ, so it doesn't apply here. And clearly the debugger is bad here since it doesn't evaluate the way the code does.

Comment: Excellent answers on that other post by the way ;)

Comment: `-1` is an integer literal. The debug viewer probably doesn't perform the implicit cast, which I suspect is language-specific behaviour

Comment: That means that the debugger doesn't actually run the code the way the CLR / compiler does, which we already knew @Pan :)

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ On the question you linked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33362835/993547 :)

Comment: The debugger in this case evaluates a debugger expression, not actual code. It does look strange though debugging in C# doesn't use the C# conversion rules.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - haha I'd totally missed that. Right, let me have this coffee and start the day over again. Slow start so far.