# .Equals versus == difference. What is the explanation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, equality

I have this EF 6 query:

```
var semana = servicio.Semana.Where(s => s.SemanaDia.Equals(ds.Dia)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Where `ds.Dia` is an integer an equal to 2. `servicio` is an entity and `semana` is a related table.

When debugging, I see that `servicio.Semana` contains a value that matchs the criteria, however, that query returns `null`.

If I replace `.Equals` by `==`, the record is retrieved and assigned to `semana` variable.

What may be the explanation to this?

`SemanaDia` is also an integer in the database.

Comment: is any of these fields a nullable field?

Comment: What is the type of `SemanaDia`? Is it string? Are you comparing an integer with a string?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals As that deals with the difference of the two in code, here it's about how they are translated to SQL by EF.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the SQL that is generated by the two.  You can do that by doing `servicio.Semana.Where(s => s.SemanaDia.Equals(ds.Dia)).ToString()`, then change it to use `==` and see the difference in the SQL.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini  you will have the answer in the question itself.

Comment: @PabloCG no.... database field is `int not null`

Comment: @jstuardo I mean in c# code, are they `int` or `int?` ?

Comment: @Progman This involves database. The difference is only when trying to compare an int field in the database with an int variable. It is not very usefull to try to do a test case.

Comment: @juharr Good idea. I don't have time right now, but I will do that soon.

Comment: Database field: `int not null`. Integer variable: `int`

Comment: @jstuardo If you provide a MCVE it is possible that everyone can test it and maybe even provide an answer to the problem. `Equals()` should work unless you have done something somewhere we currently can't see.

Comment: Finally, I have seen there is no related SQL statement with the filter. The query is performed in the statement before the comparison. The instruction before that is using `servicio.Semana`. When EF reachs that instruction, the SQL query is performed filling all records of `servicio.Semana` related property `ICollection`. Well, the only difference with the returned data is this: returned 
`semana.SemanaDia` is of type `short` while `ds.Dia` is of type int. So, maybe the question should be: why `Equals` method does not work well when comparing `short` variable to `int` variable.

Comment: Please see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/klHd8q. I have used that fiddle to test. I finally read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362737/equals-int-and-short-c-sharp-returns-false that explains why.